# SIGCHLD signal does not issued when child resume

Tags: c, unix, process, signals

Here is my signal handler:

```
pid_t pid;
int status;
while (pid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG|WUNTRACED|WCONTINUED))
{
     printf("resume? %d\n", WIFCONTINUED(status));
}
```

It always prints out 0 even if I send a `SIGCONT` to a child process. If I send a `SIGCONT` to a group of processes using `killpg`, some processes are indicated to be resumed but some are not. Could somebody tell me why this happened?

Comment: The code snippet is missing a couple of closing parentheses. Also, remember that `waitpid` returns `-1` on error, and as `-1` is non-zero it is considered true.

Answer (score 1):

The `SIGCHLD` signal is only if a child has stopped or terminated, not when execution resumes.